# codeigniter show attachment image in body email

Tags: codeigniter, email, inline, attachment

so i want to send an email html template using codeigniter.
in that template, i want to embed some images. i already tried to send image as attachment and success, the problem is, i couldn't show the attached images to my html body template.

this is the controller`

class sendMails extends CI_Controller {

```
public function htmlmail(){
    $config = Array(        
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'email',
        'smtp_pass' => 'pass',
        'smtp_timeout' => '4',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('enmail', 'name');
    //$data = array(
         //'userName'=> 'uname'
        //     );

    $userEmail = "email";
    $subject = "testing email";
    $this->email->to($userEmail);  // replace it with receiver mail id
    $this->email->subject($subject); // replace it with relevant subject 
    $logo = $this->email->attach('images/logo.jpg', 'inline');
    $menuApp = $this->email->attach('images/menuApp.jpg','inline');
    $tengah2 = $this->email->attach('images/tengah2.jpg','inline');
    $cid = $this->email->attachment_cid($logo);
    $cids = $this->email->attachment_cid($menuApp);
    $cidss = $this->email->attachment_cid($tengah2);

    //$body = $this->load->view('emails/emailAlfamind.php','',TRUE);
    //$this->email->message($body);   
    //$this->email->send();


    $message = '<!DOCTYPE html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8"><title></title></head><body>';
    $message  .= '<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="774" style="border-collapse: collapse; border:none">';
    $message  .= '  <tr>';
    $message  .= '     <td width="780" height="30px" align="center" bgcolor="#ED0A28"> <font color="#FFFFFF" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="-1" > <b>  Customer Service ALFAMIND: (021) 1500 959 </b></font><!--<img src="http://i.imgur.com/pM5yp5l.jpg" width="800" height="100%" pointer-events:"none"/>--></td>';
    $message  .= '  </tr>';
    $message  .= '  <tr>';
    $message  .= '     <td bgcolor="#E6E7E9" align="center" ;><br/> <img src= cid:"$cid" alt="logo" /> <br/><p></p></td>';
    $message  .= '  </tr>';
    $message  .= '  <tr>';
    $message  .= '    <td bgcolor="#E6E7E9">';
    $message  .= '     <table align="center" width="735"  bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0">';
    $message  .= '          <tr>';
    $message  .= '            <td> ';
    $message  .= '            asdasd';
    $message  .= '            </td>';
    $message  .= '          </tr>';
    $message  .= '   </table>';
    $message  .= '  </td>';
    $message  .= '</tr>';
    $message  .= '<tr>';
    $message  .= '  <td bgcolor="#E6E7E9" >';
    $message  .= '   <table align="center" border="0" height="75px" bgcolor="#E6E7E9" >';
    $message  .= '    <tr>';
    $message  .= '      <td width="10">&nbsp;    ';
    $message  .= '        </td>';
    $message  .= '           <td width="472">';
    $message  .= '              <table align="center" border="0" height="75px" width="468" bgcolor="#E6E7E9">';
    $message  .= '                 <tr>';
    $message  .= '                      <td colspan="3">';
    $message  .= '                          <font color="#181818" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2" > ';
    $message  .= '                               Jika anda memiliki pertanyaan lebih lanjut,  silakan hubungi kami melalui:';
    $message  .= '                           </font>';
    $message  .= '                      </td>';
    $message  .= '                  </tr>';
    $message  .= '                  <tr>';
    $message  .= '                    <td width="166">';
    $message  .= '                          <font color="#575757" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2" > ';
    $message  .= '                           <b>';
    $message  .= '                          E-mail: email';
    $message  .= '                          <br/>';
    $message  .= '                           SMS Center: num';
    $message  .= '                          </b>';
    $message  .= '                           </font>';
    $message  .= '                    </td>';
    $message  .= '                       <td width="32">';
    $message  .= '                          <img src= cid:"$cids" alt="logo" " width="31" height="55"/>';
    $message  .= '                      </td>';
    $message  .= '                      <td width="260">';
    $message  .= '                           <font color="#575757" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2" > ';
    $message  .= '                          <b>';
    $message  .= '                           PT. Sumber Alfaria Trijaya Tbk.'; 
    $message  .= '                           <br/>';
    $message  .= '                           Jl. M.H. Thamrin No.9, Cikokol, Tangerang';
    $message  .= '                           </b>';
    $message  .= '                           </font>';
    $message  .= '                      </td>';
    $message  .= '                   </tr>';
    $message  .= '              </table>';
    $message  .= '           </td>';
    $message  .= '           <td width="270" ><a href="http://www.alfamind.id"><img src= cid:"$cidss" alt="logo" " width="263" height="100"/></a></td>';
    $message  .= '       </tr>';
    $message  .= '      </table>';
    $message  .= '     </td>';
    $message  .= '    </tr>';
    $message  .= '   <tr>';
    $message  .= '    <td bgcolor="#ED0A28" height="30px" align="center"> <font color="#FFFFFF" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="-1" > Copyright &copy; 2016 ALFAMIND. All rights reserved.      </font>';
    $message  .= '   </tr>';
    $message  .= '   </table>';
    $message  .= '</body></html>';

    //$this->email->message("<img src='cid:". $cid ."' alt='photo1' />");
    $this->email->message($message);
    if(!$this->email->send())
        {
            echo "gagal";
        }else{
            echo "sukses";
        }
}
```

}`

as you can se, i already tried to call the image using the  part but it doesn't work
could you give me a solution for my problem? thank you

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$filename = '/img/photo1.jpg';
$this->email->attach($filename);
foreach ($list as $address)
{
        $this->email->to($address);
        $cid = $this->email->attachment_cid($filename);
        $this->email->message('<img src='cid:". $cid ."' alt="photo1" />');
        $this->email->send();
}
```

Documenttation:
[CodeIgniter Documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#CI_Email::attachment_cid)